# Jersey FormDataParam fails with 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, http, jersey, multipartform-data, dropwizard

I have a very weird behaviour from Jersey and `FormDataParam` when trying to upload an image to my service. My service runs on Dropwizard.

The method that accepts an image (along with metadata object) looks like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/photos")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    fun upload(
        @FormDataParam("photo") fileInputStream: FileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("metadata") metadata: PhotoMetadataV1RequestModel
    ) {
        // do something
    }
```

I've registered `MultipartFeature` in the Guice module.

```
public class JerseyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // other stuff

        bind(MultiPartFeature.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }

}
```

I've added a `jersey-multipart` dependency in the `build.gradle`.

```
    // Jersey
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:$jerseyVersion"
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:$jerseyVersion"
```

Now the funny part.

This actually **works** if I try to upload a file using an absolute path! BUT, it does NOT work I try to upload a file using a relative path.

More importantly, it also does NOT work when a service is deployed on another machine (not the same the upload image request is coming from). This is important, because I deploy my service to Heroku, and I need to upload images from other places!

**This is what works** (absolute path for the `photo`):

```
curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8095/rest/v1/self/photos" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer GaKC8xQju5h" \
--form 'photo=/Users/whizzil/Desktop/nova_scripts/create_users/user-lina/photos-webp/photo-profile-1.webp' \
--form 'metadata={"photoType": "PROFILE", "position": 2};type=application/json'
```

However, even this does NOT work if the url of the server is not localhost, but e.g. Heroku server.

**This is what does NOT work** (relative path for the `photo`):

```
curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8095/rest/v1/self/photos" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer GaKC8xQju5h" \
--form 'photo=@./photo-profile-1.webp' \
--form 'metadata={"photoType": "PROFILE", "position": 2};type=application/json'
```

The exception that is thrown when it doesn't work:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ExtractorException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ExtractorException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParamException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider$FormDataParamValueFactory.provide(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:352)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
```

I am lost here. I tried googling everything, but no success. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a naive question but why do you suffix the relative path with a `@` char in the `photo` attribute in the second curl? Relative path or not this makes a difference between the two requests if I'm right.

Comment: So maybe, you may falsely believe that the first request works but does not. And by the way you could try writing the relative path without the `./` suffix.

Comment: No the first request definitely does work. It returns 200 OK and the photo ends up in the DB. The 2nd request returns 400 Bad Request and the photo does not end up in the DB.

Comment: Every time you say "does not work," this means that the result is the exception you posted?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Yes, exactly. The input-stream does get read, but for some reason it throws the invalid file path. 

I know that it gets read, because if I change the form param from `photo` to i.e. `bla` then it throws that the `InputStream` is `null`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Works fine for me. The only difference is that I registered the MultiPartFeature with Jersey and not Guice. But I don't think that is the problem because the exception shows that multipart classes are being used. Could you make a minimal GitHub repo that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `FileInputStream` to `InputStream` solved the issue. I have no idea why, though.

Comment: I didn't catch the `FileInputStream` part of your post. The reason for the exception is because the MessageBodyReader was written to [only accept InputStream.class](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2.31/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/InputStreamProvider.java#L44) as a readable type.